# Doubts about the decrement function of the RB-Tree iterator

Tags: c++, stl, set, red-black-tree

I'm writing a STL-like container library js-sdsl in Js mode.

There is a question about the [decrement function](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/4832767db7897be6fb5cbc44f079482c90cb95a6/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/src/c%2B%2B98/tree.cc#L95) (forward function of the iterator) in STL RB-Tree.

When I insert two different values into the Tree from small to large, I will get an RB-Tree with the following structure:

[image: rb-tree]

Among them, the **Root** node and the **Header** node are parents and children of each other, and the left and right nodes of the **Header** node point to the two inserted values respectively, and the smaller value will become the **Root** node, and the larger value will become the right child node of **Root**.

At this point, when the iterator pointing to the **Root** node is decremented, the following steps will be taken:

1. Judging that it is not currently a Header node, go to step 2;
2. Judging that the left child node of the current pointer is empty, go to step 3;
3. Determine that the current node (**Root**) is the left child node of the parent node (**Header**) (note that at this time, the **LeftMost** of the **Header** points to the smallest node in the tree, that is, **Root**), so move the pointer to the parent node (**Header**), and repeat step 3 until no more If the conditions are met, go to step 4;
4. Obviously, because the Root node and the **Header** node are parents and children of each other, the pointer finally points to the Root node after step 3.

In the end, the following code should fall into an infinite loop:

```cpp
set<int> st { 1, 2 };
for (auto it = st.rbegin(); it != st.rend(); ++it) {
    cout << *it <<endl;
}
```

But actually, the above code works fine, I'm confused, I don't see any special handling in the STL code, I'm not proficient in C++, can anyone help me solve this problem?

Grateful!

Why above code works fine

Comment: *I don't see any special handling in the STL code* -- First, there is no requirement at all for `std::set` to be implemented this way.  This is all compiler and implementation dependent as to *how* this is done.  You are looking at one particular implementation (which you haven't told us what compiler you are using), and if you compare that to another compiler's implementation, may look completely different.  Thus maybe you should just forget what a compiler's implementation is doing, and work this out from scratch using pencil and paper, and then implement this in javascript.

Comment: But the implementation of the C++ red-black tree algorithm in each version is roughly the same? I guess.

Comment: @ZilongYao Absolutely not guaranteed in any way. Actually, it does not even have to be red-black tree. I wouldn't be surprised if it's indeed red-black tree everywhere, but I would be slightly surprised if implementations use exactly the same invariants and exactly the same logic.

Comment: Another suggestion: create a `set`, and then go through your loop step-by-step with a debugger. It should be able to enter into iterator's logic and you will see what's going on in your specific case with your specific implementation. Maybe it works, maybe it uses some tricks to do some extra work, who knows, debugger will tell you for sure.

Comment: Yes, it's really a good idea, but I found that it uses a lot of syntax and tricks inside that I don't understand, and I think I need more time to learn it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood how the `std::reverse_iterator` works: when the overloaded `operator*` is called, the underlying iterator is decremented and then dereferenced. More details can be found at [std::reverse_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator).

The loop should be interpreted in the following way:

1. At first loop, the iterator, that is currently `rbegin()`, is dereferenced, that means the underlying iterator is decremented and then dereferenced. Since the iterator points to the sentinel node (Header), the decrement function moves it to its right child node, that is the rightmost node by definition.
2. At second loop, the updated iterator is dereferenced, that means the underlying iterator is decremented and then dereferenced. Since the iterator points to an external node, its left child node is null and then the decrement function moves it to its parent node (Root).
3. Finally, since the updated iterator is now equal to the `rend()`, that is the root node, the loop is broken.

Effectively, your observation about the decrement of the `begin()` iterator is right: if it is decremented, it refers again to itself.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! But I still have two question: 1. Why the `rend` equals to the root when use `reverse_iterator`? 2. According to the source code of each version, the leftmost or rightmost element is 'constant' value which pointer to the Header node's left or right.

Comment: 1. The `rend()` is simply an instance of the `std::reverse_iterator` that wraps an iterator pointing to the `begin()`. Then, it points to the leftmost node, and in this case the leftmost node is represented by the root node.

Comment: 2. My implementation of the red-black tree is an abstraction I created for a personal project. The Header and Root nodes are respectively parent and left child. In this way, the Header node appears to be a simple node, the first node inserted and the largest of all. And the leftmost node is the right child of the Header node. To allow cyclic iteration and have constant access to the leftmost node, that is the smallest node, is interpreted as the larger node of the Header node. This ensures to use the same algorithms without treating the Root or Header node as separate cases.